# How can I use JWT tokens in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-jwt

I'm new to django and DRF, I'm trying to build an authentification system using JWT, I want to login the user directly after registering, I read the documentation and I managed to create a token manually and return it in my serializer, but my questions are this:

1) How can I use this token to see if the user is logged in or not?

2) Can I use the {% if user.is_authenticated %} in my templates? if so how?

3) How can I get the user logged in informations in another view?

4) Is there a more efficient way of dealing with authentifications with DRF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- Basically when you are using DRF and jwt token, Means you are using token-based authentication, So all your requests should contains a http header for `Authorization: basic <token value>`. So django drf authentication backend, will recognize this token and if valid, user will be authenticated.

2- I don't think you can use that templatetag anymore. Because that's for session based authentications.

3- if you provide the authentication backed for that token and send the token in header, every view should has user info in `request.user`

4- One of the best solutions in my opinion is token-based with jwt tokens.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm new to this, how can I add a http header? And how can I get the user's token in a different request? Should I recreate the token manually?

Comment: no just send it from UI in your requests. just in your javascript code add a header with value `Authorization: basic <token>`

Comment: for example you can test it using this curl command: `http http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello/ 'Authorization: Token <token here>'`

Comment: Oh i see thanks a lot, but how can i logout a user then with jwt?

Comment: You can't destroy a jwt token. but you can remove it from UI by removing from localStorage or Cookies. But the jwt token will be valid until it expires.

Answer (score 0):

[DRF Auth and Permissions](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions/) has a lot of useful information on working with auth and permissions in DRF, check it out.

Adding on to what @Reza-Torkaman-Ahmadi said:

In your views you can use permissions to make sure a user is authenticated:

```
permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)
```